# How to center element vertically?

Tags: html, css

This question perhaps was asked before, but my case is somehow special.

I have two divs one inside the other. Both divs heights are unknown, but what I can tell about the outer div is its minimal height. The point is - I want the smaller div to center vertically inside the outer div if the inner div is smaller than the outer. And I want the inner div to expand the outer div if it is bigger than the minimal height of the outer div.

I would like to achieve this without using any scripts.

Is it even possible?

Sample code:

```
<div id="outer" style="min-height:50px;">
   <div id="inner">
       Im here, I could be short, I could be long 
       and if I wrap - i could be tall
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes.. Now what have you tried. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/ may be useful

Comment: Not possible without script. Also please provide sample code so that we can see and make changes.

Comment: This is perfectly possible with flexbox.

Comment: try this: `display:table-cell; vertical-align:center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: middle`. Boom.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #BBB;
  margin: 10px;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Im here, I could be short, I could be long and if I wrap - i could be tall
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Im here, I could be short, I could be long</p>
    <p>and if I wrap - i could be tall</p>
    <p>Im here, I could be short, I could be long</p>
    <p>and if I wrap - i could be tall</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `flexbox`. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3enw3178/)

```
#outer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a useful guide to Flexbox

Answer (score -1):

Basically, without any script(JS/Jquery) it's not possible. With only css you can't say the smaller div to put inside the other and align it vertically.

As you said in your question, the keyword "if" explains itselfs. For what you want, you have to use some script code. Css can only declare the styles of the elements, not the conditions of one about the other.

Comment: This is 100% possible without JS. Please see the other two answers to this question.